# Error:Error: Expected resource of type menu [ResourceType] when I click 'Generate Signed APK'?

Tags: java, android-studio, opengl-es, pong

[Click Here for Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKJEc.jpg)

On `Android Studio`, I'm creating a Ping Pong Game and cannot generate Signed APK file due to an error I keep getting.

I go to Generate Signature `APK` and I get an error that reads:

> "Error:Error: Expected resource of type menu [ResourceType]"

that displays in the messages section. When I select 'Jump to Source' to see what the error is,
it opens up my Pong3D.java file and doesn't display anything in red text... but it does highlight a section that reads: Game _game;

I am stuck on what to do here. All I know is that when I try to generate an `APK` file, I keep getting this same error.  Why does this error appear and what does it mean?

Comment: Could you fix it?